# Trust e-mail from our domain(s)

Tags: email, exchange, outlook, group-policy, spam-filter

We have several notification e-mails that get generated by various systems for our users. I've been asked to make sure all e-mail to [anything]@ourcompany.com doesn't wind up in our users' junk folders.

What is the best and easiest way(s) to do this?

I have seen that you can write a GPO for Outlook to import a list, but it seems like a one-off import... I'm not really sure how that would be manageable in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Exchange 2007/2010, you can write Transport Rules that will set the SCL level on messages. This influences Outlook's decision to junkmail emails, but isn't 100%. We've also received the 'Shall Deliver' directive for certain messages and spent quite some time explaining how that's not really possible without *taking away* certain functionality. Specifically, the ability of users to manage their own black/white lists inside Outlook.

I'm not sure how to solve this for Exchange 2000/2003.

Comment: We are on Exchange 2007, so I'll look into SCL levels

Comment: I've given the same speech now to our management and it's getting tossed around, but thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @garret Hooray! Glad to be of service.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to just add the system IP's to the allowed hosts on the receive connectors and leave the actual email filtering to the anti-spam filters. This way you will reduce the spam that may otherwise enter in the given mailbox.